# Python: Spatially interpolate between two lat/lon grids with different dimensions and resolution

Tags: python, coordinate-system, georeferencing

Let's say that I have two datasets.

The first dataset is sized [14000,7000] and represents terrain data throughout the CONUS. This data is equally-spaced 0.005-degrees in terms of latitude / longitude. for example:

```
print(biglons[0:10])
print(biglats[0:10])
[-130.0, -129.995, -129.99, -129.985, -129.98, -129.975, -129.97, -129.965, -129.96, -129.955]
[55.0, 54.995, 54.99, 54.985, 54.98, 54.975, 54.97, 54.965, 54.96, 54.955]
```

I then have a second dataset that is [x,y] dimensions large, and is projected with the following:

```
dataproj = Proj(f"+proj=eqc +lat_0={latitude} +lat_ts={latitude} +lon_0={longitude} +ellps=WGS84 +units=m")
lons,lats = dataproj(x,y,inverse=True)
```

lons / lats are a subset within biglons / biglats, but do not match up properly as they are projected differently and the spacing for lons/lats is smaller than that of biglons and biglats. In order to match, I loop through each index of lons[i] and lats[j] to match as closely as possible to the value in biglons and biglats. Something like:

```
   from pyproj import Proj
   # new_trn = terrain values corresponding to the locations at biglons and biglats.
   # Loop a
    for a in range(0,lons.shape[0]):

        # Loop r
        for r in range(0,lats.shape[0]):

            # Access the elements
            tmp_lon = lons[a][r]
            tmp_lat = lats[a][r]

            # Now we need to find where the tmp_lon and tmp_lat match best with the index from biglats and biglons
            idx = (np.abs(biglats - tmp_lat)).argmin()
            idy = (np.abs(biglons - tmp_lon)).argmin()

            # Make our final array!
            data_trn[a,r] = bigtrn[idy,idx]
```

The problem is this is extremely slow and inefficient. Is there a better method of doing this, especially more quickly?